# How To Create Bio Info Descipton Read More Jump Link (WP)

Tags: jquery

How To Create Bio Info Descripton Read More (click for full reading at same page) When Characters Is More Than 320 Characters.

Below is my bio info description on [This Page](http://webresepi.com/author/shahrul/).

```
<p><?php echo $curauth->description; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/S8Cxr/

HTML:

```
<p id="bio">I am a sahm (stay at home mom) mom of 8, passionately interested in...well..my interests! I am restoring a 100 year old farm house, homeschooling the six kids still at home, raising Nigerian Dwarf Dairy goats, and trying to change our lives and those around us by the decisions and choices we make daily. I love reading, spinning fiber, sewing, cooking, writing, painting, crafting, antiquing...and just about anything shiny can grab my interest for a bit..Well maybe I am not that bad.</p>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bio = $('#bio');
    var text = bio.text();

    if (text.length > 320) {
        bio.html(text.slice(0, 320) + '<span class="more">... (<a class="expand" href="#">more</a>)</span><span class="hidden">' + text.slice(320) + '</span>');

        $('.expand').on('click', function(event) {
            $(event.target)
                .closest('p')
                .find('.hidden')
                    .removeClass('hidden')
                    .end()            
                .find('.more')
                    .remove();
        });
    }    
});​
```

Comment: Hi Cymen, Thanks so much for this code.

But after trying put this code,

<p id="bio"><?php echo $curauth->description; ?></p>
<script>
your JavaScript
</script> .. Its not working on my site :(

Comment: You need to include jQuery on your page to use it. You can use the CDN version from here by linking: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js so at top of page: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: Hi Cymen, im really appreciate it. i know its a true function and this code is working. But i dont know why in my site, it still does not work. :(

Comment: Are you using `<script type="text/javascript">` at the beginning? Is it on your page now (I didn't see it) -- I could check it there if you add it.

Comment: Hi Cymen, Thank you for your concern. Now you can see at my page source at line 70 and 95. Tell me if there is a need to change. Thanks Cymen :)

Comment: @user1620427 The problem remains the same: you need jQuery included on the page for it to work. Put this in your `header` area: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Hi Cymen, i have done put this script on my header data section. But it still does not work in my site :( .

Comment: @user1620427 The bio.js file on your website has a bad character at the end of the file. It's here: http://webresepi.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_185/custom/bio.js If you remove that, it should work.

Comment: Hi Cymen, i dont know why that character there :( . Anyway in my cpanel, full js code is like this screenshoot (http://goo.gl/PPLPy) . 

But its shown with this bad Character like this screenshoot (http://goo.gl/WEFJK).

Comment: @user1620427 I would try simply deleting the last line and then typing in `});` and saving it again. Maybe it will fix it?

Comment: Yes, finally it working on my site @Cymen !! :D Thank you very² much Cymen. :D